# Como puedo mostrar todas las imágenes que tengo guardadas en la base de datos Postgre en un JFrame en NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, postgresql-9.3

//Este es mi código pero solo me muestra una sola imagen

```
String sql="select imagen from \"libros\"  ";
    ImageIcon foto;
    InputStream is;


    try{
        ResultSet rs = con.ejecutarSQLSelect(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            is = rs.getBinaryStream(1);

            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(is);
            foto = new ImageIcon(bi);

            Image img = foto.getImage();
            Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(140, 170, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

            ImageIcon newicon = new ImageIcon(newimg);

            LBL_LIBRO.setIcon(newicon);

        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"exception: "+ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LBL_LIBRO.setIcon(newicon);
```

Solo tienes un label, que muestra un icono, y en cada iteración le dices que muestre un icono distinto. Al hacer el `setIcon` descarta el valor anterior y se queda con el nuevo.

Solución: Ve creando (y añadiendo al `Container) tantos`JLabel` como necesites, cada uno con su imagen.